# call wcf service from javascript or asp.net method

Tags: javascript, vb.net, wcf

I have a asp.net web application with jquery controls. I have a datagrid that will display data from a database table and created a WCF Service to access the db and return the data. I want to be able to call the WCF service from this application which is on a different server and have the xml data returned, converted to json format to be used in the datagrid which is a jquery widget. I have tested the web service and it works fine. Should I call the web service from the javascript function within the xml or create a .net method behind that calls the service and then does the conversion? From these how would I get started? Any ideas/links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a webHttpBinding to allow you to call your WCF service directly from javascript

Comment: Have a read through the official page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx, then there's a few blogs out there, like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bashmohandes/archive/2008/01/05/using-webhttpbinding-json-support-in-wcf.aspx